# Google Freebase API whitelist IP not being accepted (server-side key)

Tags: google-api, api-key, whitelist

Is there a way to find out what IP address Google is checking against the Whitelist? I've looked at the report page, historical usage, etc. but I cannot find any logs.

Here is the issue, I have set up a Server-Side API key with a set of whitelisted API keys. On my local machine, this works perfectly - the IP address is accepted and I get a response.

On our web server, however, I get the following exception with a 403 response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "usageLimits", 
        "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.", 
        "reason": "accessNotConfigured", 
        "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is a pretty typical response if the API Whitelist is not set up correctly, however, when I do the following:

```
~$ curl -s checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

I get the IP address that I have in the whitelist (this is the equivalent of using IPChicken.com or something, it tells you what the outside world thinks your IP address). So why am I getting API errors? If I copy the same exact link with the same exact key into my localhost, (whose IP address is also added to the whitelist) I get a 200 response.

How do I find out what IP Address Google sees to check against the whitelist?